# he looked relaxed, if pale -- "if pale"?

Tags: word-meaning, conjunctions

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/russias-putin-appears-public-first-time-since-march-110328013--finance.html):

> "It would be boring without gossip," Putin said, smiling easily before television cameras. He looked relaxed, **if pale**.

Could you please explain how this expression is actually used? I have a hunch that this must mean the same thing as saying *even though he was pale, he looked relaxed*. Do you think my interpretation is correct?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, Cookie Monster. The answers below just add more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This use of *if* is showing a contrast between two elements--in this case, *relaxed* and *pale*. The sentence could be reworded in the way you suggested, or in this (more decisive) way: He looked relaxed **but** pale. (Using *but* indicates a greater degree of certainty on the part of the speaker.)

The construction (X, if Y) tends to present a positive, primary element followed by a negative, secondary one that runs counter to and "detracts" from it.

> When police located the missing child, he was **safe, if scared**.

The same meaning can be conveyed thus:

> Despite being scared, the missing child was safe when police located him.

Comment: @BenKovitz Done. I see I was being rather vague there.

Comment: I'd like to add that 'if (pale)' used in this way is generally a 'weaker' form than 'but (pale)'. You will often find it used as 'if perhaps somewhat (pale)', whereas 'but (pale)' means he's definitely looking rather pale.

Comment: @sanchises Excellent point. I incorporated it into an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much, yes. In that context, "if" means "even though (he looked)".

Now, that said, the "if" formulation could indicate, on the part of the speaker, a little less certainty, or more hesitancy, than "even though" does. The "if" version intentionally leaves a little bit of scope for the speaker being incorrect -- i.e. they *think* Putin was pale, but they could be wrong. The "even though" version loses that uncertainty, and is basically asserting that Putin is pale.